# How can I Draw a line on high and low of last bar of a session, and extend it to the last bar of next session, in Pine Editor?

Tags: session, time, line, pine-script

I am trying to draw a line on high and low of the last bar in a session.  I would like those lines to extend to the last bar of next session? It would be nice to have an option to fill in the space w/ a background color, but that is not the main goal. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Last bar though can be dependent on Time frame you are using?

Have a look the below script.

You should able to copy and change the timings to suit.

https://uk.tradingview.com/script/30iJncRa-Initial-Balance-Markets-Time-Zones/